# Hitting Max number of files and blobs for Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

When trying to deploy my application:

```
appcfg.py update --oauth2 .
```

I'm getting:

```
PM Rolling back the update.
Error 400: --- begin server output ---
Max number of files and blobs is 10000.
--- end server output ---
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You "solve" it by having less files deployed when you deploy your project. You have a few choices.

You can use [Skipfiles](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Skipping_files) in your app.yaml to exclude some files from being deployed:

```
skip_files:
- ^(.*/)?#.*#$
- ^(.*/)?.*~$
- ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
- ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
- ^(.*/)?\..*$
```

You might want to, for example, exclude .readme files, compiled python files etc.

Or you can use [ZipImport](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipimport.html) and compress your python packages and they will be unzipped on the fly during import.

Or if you are also uploading lots of static assets, put them in a bucket instead as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are hitting this quota: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas#Deployments

Could you shift many of your files to [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp)?

Comment: It mentions 10,000 per version, I tried adding half the files on version 1, and the other half on version 2, but it counted them all again (maybe I understood it wrong)..

Comment: Could also be "The current quota is 10,000 per day."